# Phonegap not rotating orientation?

Tags: ios, cordova

I'm not sure why, but my PhoneGap app is not rotating the screen when I rotate my iPhone. It'd be useless to post the code, as it doesn't work with the simplest of code: `<div>Hello World!</div`.

I have the orientation settings checked too:
[image]
[image]

And here's an example (same happens on actual device):
[image]

Comment: Care to explain the down vote?

Comment: Having this same problem.  All orientations are listed as supported in my plist and shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation returns YES in all ViewController files....

Answer (score 3):

Same problem to me. I solved it adding following lines for iOS6 on my delegate:

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication*)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow*)window
{
    NSUInteger supportedInterfaceOrientations = (1 << UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) | (1 << UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) | (1 << UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) | (1 << UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);

    return supportedInterfaceOrientations;
}
```

also, on your main controller, add:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the MainViewController.m on the classes folder

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    //return [super shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:interfaceOrientation];
     return true;
}
```

and on AppDelegate.m still on the classes folder

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication*)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow*)window
{
    // iPhone doesn't support upside down by default, while the iPad does.  Override to allow all orientations always, and let the root view controller decide what's allowed (the supported orientations mask gets intersected).
    NSUInteger supportedInterfaceOrientations = (1 << UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) | (1 << UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) | (1 << UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) | (1 << UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);

    return supportedInterfaceOrientations;
}
```